# OnValidateIdentity in OWIN Cookie authentication not called

Tags: asp.net, owin-security

I am using the OWIN cookie authentication middleware and have setup a custom `OnValidateIdentity`-method that should be invoked on all requests that needs to be authenticated.

My setup looks like this:

```
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "my-cookie",
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider()
            {
                OnValidateIdentity = async ctx =>
                {
                    // my own validation code
                }
            }
        }
```

The issue I have is that for some requests, `OnValidateIdentity` is not called. If I hit the same protected Web API controller multiple times, some of the requests would not invoke the `OnValidateIdentity`-method.

This leads to issues later in the processing when I need to use `GetOwinContext().Authentication.User` and the `ClaimsPrincipal` is not populated.

What could be the reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. The cookie was expired.

This is because I also use the `OpenIdConnect`-middleware using the same cookie. Turns out that if you don't specify `UseTokenLifetime = false` in that config, it will use the expiry of the ID token as cookie expiry.